# Identify HtmlElement under cursor in WebBrowser

Tags: html, vb.net, winforms, dom

I'm trying to set up a small extension of WebBrowser control as an HtmlTextBox, with limited formatting possibilities. It works for basic formatting (bold, italic, underline). But I also wanted to allow indentation in one single level, and ideally call this in a "toggle" fashion.

I noticed that when I run `Document.ExecCommand("Indent", False, Nothing)` it converts the `<p>` element into a `<blockquote>` element, which is exactly what I need. But a second call to the same command just adds to the indent margin, but I want to make it so that, if cursor is already inside a `<blockquote>` element, it will perform an "outdent" instead.

For that, I tried to query `Document.ActiveElement` before performing my action, but this returns always the whole `<body>` element, and not the specific block element in which cursor rests at that moment.

How could I accomplish that?

This is my code:

```vb
Public Class HtmlTextBox
    Inherits WebBrowser

    Public Sub New()
        WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = False
        IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
        DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>"
        If Document IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim doc = Document.DomDocument
            If doc IsNot Nothing Then
                doc.designMode = "On"
                If Me.ContextMenuStrip Is Nothing Then
                    AddHandler Document.ContextMenuShowing, Sub(sender As Object, e As HtmlElementEventArgs) Application.DoEvents()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub HtmlTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Me.PreviewKeyDown
        If e.Control Then
            If e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.B) OrElse e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.N) Then BoldToggle()
            If e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.I) Then ItalicToggle()
            If e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.S) OrElse e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.U) Then UnderlineToggle()
            If e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.M) Then BlockQuoteToggle()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub BoldToggle()
        Document.ExecCommand("Bold", False, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ItalicToggle()
        Document.ExecCommand("Italic", False, Nothing)
    End Sub
    Public Sub UnderlineToggle()
        Document.ExecCommand("Underline", False, Nothing)
    End Sub
    Public Sub BlockQuoteToggle()
        If Document.ActiveElement.TagName.ToLower = "blockquote" Then
            Document.ExecCommand("Outdent", False, Nothing)
        Else
            Document.ExecCommand("Indent", False, Nothing)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I played with creating an Html Editor once and worked a means of getting the element at selection start, but it uses the mshtml library and also Reflection.  Do you have any aversion to using the mshtml library and/or Reflection.  If not, I can post the relevant code.  It gets a bit ugly.

Comment: Hi, I'll thank you a lot if you do. No aversion at all. I just prefer late binding instead of referencing MSHTML, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `ElementAtSelectionStart` is designed to return the element containing the start of the current selection.  This code is for a WebBrowser control in edit mode.  Hopefully it will work for your needs.

```
Public Class mshtmlUtilities
   Public Enum C_Bool
      [False] = 0
      [True] = 1
   End Enum

   Public Shared Function ElementAtSelectionStart(ByVal wb As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
      Dim el As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement = Nothing

      If wb IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
         wb.Document IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
         DirectCast(wb.Document.DomDocument, mshtml.IHTMLDocument2).designMode.Equals("on", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then

         Dim doc As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = DirectCast(wb.Document.DomDocument, mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)
         Dim sel As mshtml.IHTMLSelectionObject = DirectCast(doc.selection, mshtml.IHTMLSelectionObject)
         Select Case sel.type.ToLowerInvariant
            Case "text"
               Dim rng As mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange = DirectCast(sel.createRange(), mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange)
               rng.collapse(True)
               el = MakeWinFormHTMLElement(rng.parentElement, wb)
            Case "control"
               Dim rng As mshtml.IHTMLControlRange = DirectCast(sel.createRange(), mshtml.IHTMLControlRange)
               el = MakeWinFormHTMLElement(rng.item(0).parentElement, wb)
            Case "none"
               Dim ds As mshtml.IDisplayServices = DirectCast(doc, mshtml.IDisplayServices)
               Dim caret As mshtml.IHTMLCaret = Nothing
               ds.GetCaret(caret)
               Dim pt As mshtml.tagPOINT
               caret.GetLocation(pt, C_Bool.False)
               el = wb.Document.GetElementFromPoint(New Point(pt.x, pt.y))
         End Select
      End If

      Return el
   End Function

   Private Shared Function MakeWinFormHTMLElement(ByVal el As mshtml.IHTMLElement, ByVal wb As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
      Dim shimInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo = wb.GetType.GetProperty("ShimManager", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
      Dim shimManager As Object = shimInfo.GetValue(wb, Nothing)
      Dim ciElement As Reflection.ConstructorInfo() _
         = wb.Document.Body.GetType().GetConstructors(Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      Return CType(ciElement(0).Invoke(New Object() {shimManager, el}), HtmlElement)
   End Function
End Class
```

Comment: It worked! I just made a little tweak to make it instance dynamic (not `Shared`). Thank you very much!

Comment: @VBobCat, you are welcome.  I'm glad it worked for you.  On a side note, I suggest you remove the c# tag before someone dings you for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it. It would be funny if someone did it, because I add this tag for the only reason that the system insistently suggests it.